# Angular Timeout calling function without delay

Tags: angularjs

In the following snippet, the progress call is getting triggered continuously with out the 10s delay. Please let me know where i am going wrong

```
        ctrl.progress =function (fileName){

            if(ctrl.status < 100){
                ctrl.timer = $timeout(function(fileName){

                    LookUpValueService.getImportStatus(fileName).
                    then(function(value){
                        ctrl.status = value; 
                        ctrl.progress(fileName);
                    });
                    //ctrl.status = ctrl.status + 1;                

                }(fileName),5000);
            }
            else{
                $timeout.cancel(ctrl.timer);
            }
        }; ctrl.progress("test.txt");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to `$timeout()` has to be a *function* itself, not the result of a call to a function.

In your case, `ctrl.progress()` does not return a function, it returns undefined, so when you have:

```
ctrl.timer = $timeout(ctrl.progress(fileName), 10000);
```

what happens is that `ctrl.progress(fileName)` gets called immediately, returns undefined, and then you tell `$timeout()` to wait 10 seconds before doing `undefined`.

Change that line to use a function instead, and it will work:

```
ctrl.timer = $timeout(() => ctrl.progress(fileName), 10000);
```

(or if not using ES6/2015/TypeScript: `ctrl.timer = $timeout(function () { ctrl.progress(fileName) }, 10000);`)

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Changed code to as suggested in the original post , still facing same issue :(

Comment: @maheshreddy The answer is correct on that. You're doing the same thing as before. The function shouldn't be called with `(fileName)`. You're having IIFE instead of $timeout callback, which stands for **immediately invoked** function expression.

Comment: aah, Thanks, I was trying differents things and made it a IIFE. Removing the IIFE solved, it, Thanks!!